# Exception when create new Azure Service Fabric Stateful Service

Tags: c#, .net, azure-service-fabric

I have read articles about Service Fabric and Microservices approach. Then i have installed runtime, SDK and VS tools (just like there [in the doc](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-get-started/)) and executed PowerShell command. But when i have started to create new Service Fabric Application (Stateful Service, like in the example of first Service Fabric Application) i have caught an Exception in the Visual Studio:

> Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131500

What should i do to fix this exception? Or, may be, have i do something wrong? (Both Visual Studio and PowerShell have been run in Administrator mode)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's months ago you asked this question. I hope you have a solution already, but I had the same problem. To help people that will find this post in the future, here is what I did to solve the problem. There are multiple things I did.

First, I did the same as you did and followed the article you mention to install the development environment. The URL in the article to download is http://www.microsoft.com/web/handlers/webpi.ashx?command=getinstallerredirect&appid=MicrosoftAzure-ServiceFabric-VS2015-2_1
But this installed an old version on my system. When I started the platform installer on my machine, and searched for Service Fabric, a newer version can be installed.

But, unfortunately I Still get the error.

And second, after a lot of trial and error I had to turn on feature ".NET 3.5 (includes .NET 2.0 and 3.0)". After restarting Visual Studio I was finally able to create a new Service Fabric project.

Comment: Thank you very much. In my case exception was cause of the Russian language pack of the Microsoft Visual Studio 2015. As soon as I have installed English pack and enabled this feature - everything works.

Comment: Where do you turn on the ".NET 3.5 (includes .NET 2.0 and 3.0)" feature?

Comment: Open "Add or Remove Programs" in Control Panel and then
click "Add/Remove Windows Components". You must be logged on as an administrator or a member of the Administrators group in order to complete this procedure.